SSIS - Visual FoxPro OLE DB driver - .dbf + .cdx table suddenly stopped working?
I have been running a daily SSIS package in SSMS SQL Agent for 4+ months without issue. All it's doing is extracting ERP data from a .dbf table and storing it in SQL. A couple days ago it started failing and SSIS is saying the table doesn't even exist even though I can open the folder where all the .dbf files are stored and visually confirm its existence. Both the .dbf and .cdx
0xC020204A - Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.

I still don't know why it broke after running fine for months, but I found that specifying "dbase III" (I'd left the field blank until now) in the extended properties of the connection manager fixed the issue.
https://sqlserverrider.com/tag/connect-dbf-with-ssis/
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/error-reading-dbf-file-in-ssis
